# VBA Compile Error Type Mismatch - Looping with Sheet Function

Tags: excel, vba, loops, type-mismatch

Goal: Loop through a column containing rows of text, if there is a match based on worksheet function Search() criteria, output the value to another sheet.

Problem: Mismatch error on "Search" function. The Search() function on the first row of data returns #VALUE.

Tried: On the target cells containing the "X=" match I'm able to output the desired values.

```
Sub practice()

Dim coordinate As Variant
Dim myData As Range
Dim count As Integer

count = 2

Set myData = Worksheets("DATA").Range("A:A")

For Each coordinate In myData

'end loop at blank cell
    If coordinate = "" Then
        Exit For
            End If
            
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Search("X=", coordinate, 1), "") <> "" Then

    Sheets("COORDINATES").Range("A" & count) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Mid(coordinate, Application.Search("X=", coordinate, 1) + 2, Application.Search("Y=", coordinate, 1) - Application.Search("X=", coordinate, 1) - 2)
    Sheets("COORDINATES").Range("B" & count) = Applicatoin.WorksheetFunction.Mid(coordinate, Application.Search("Y=", coordinate, 1) + 2, Application.Search("Z=", coordinate, 1) - Application.Search("Y=", coordinate, 1) - 2)
    
count = count + 1

End If

Next coordinate

End Sub
```

EDIT: Adding the IfError and blank resolves the if statement.

Now the desired mid(search()) combination is returning a Run-time 438 error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: Set a variable to the result of the Search and check that for an error

Comment: @Kevin Resolved the if statement, not the mid(search()) is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mid() does not require the WorksheetFunction.Application

```
Sub practice()

Dim coordinate As Variant
Dim myData As Range
Dim count As Integer

count = 2

Set myData = Worksheets("DATA").Range("A:A")

For Each coordinate In myData

'end loop at blank cell
    If coordinate = "" Then
        Exit For
            End If
            
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Search("X=", coordinate, 1), "") <> "" Then 'Using IfError(Search(),"") resolved the #VALUE issue.

'Syntax Mid() does not require WorksheetFunction.Application
    Sheets("COORDINATES").Range("A" & count) = Mid(coordinate, Application.Search("X=", coordinate, 1) + 2, Application.Search("Y=", coordinate, 1) - Application.Search("X=", coordinate, 1) - 2)
    Sheets("COORDINATES").Range("B" & count) = Mid(coordinate, Application.Search("Y=", coordinate, 1) + 2, Application.Search("Z=", coordinate, 1) - Application.Search("Y=", coordinate, 1) - 2)
   

count = count + 1

End If

Next coordinate

End Sub
```